# How to let a subclass inherit a variable without a value in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a BankAccount abstract class that have two subclassses - SavingsAccount and CreditAccount. Both subclasses share a set of variables that will have different values, e.g. 1% interestrate for SavingsAccount and 0.5% for CreditAccount. Since they also share several methods that are using the interestRate variable I would like them to inherit the variable and the methods using it (instead of writing these methods twice).

Can I somehow have the subclasses inherit the interestRate variable and give it the value I want in the subclasses, or is there some other way to go about solving this?

Comment: Not only *can* you, it's normal. What have you tried? If you're running into a problem, we can help you figure out what it is if you show us the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Can you show some code illustrating your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved it now. It didn't work because the variable was final

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this (at least);

1. Give your base class a constructor (don't worry, it'll still be abstract) that initializes the instance variable, and provide protected accessors for the variables.
2. Make the instance variables protected.

Example:

```
abstract class BankAccount {
    private BigDecimal interestRate;

    protected BankAccount(BigDecimal interestRate) {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    protected BigDecimal getInterestRate() {
        return this.interestRate;
    }
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    public SavingsAccount(BigDecimal interestRate) {
        super(interestRate);
    }
    // ...code in methods can use `this.getInterestRate()`...
}
```

or (but I **don't** recommend it):

```
abstract class BankAccount {
    protected BigDecimal interestRate;

    protected BankAccount(BigDecimal interestRate) {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    public SavingsAccount(BigDecimal interestRate) {
        super(interestRate);
    }
    // ...code in methods can use `this.interestRate` directly...
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you. But there's no way to make the interestRate variable final this way right?

Comment: @ronaldfisher - It's effectively final in the first example above, since `BankAccount` only supplies a `getter`. In the second example, there's no reason you can't declare `interestRate` `final`: `protected final BigDecimal interestRate;` A `final` instance variable (field) can be initialized in an initializer *or* in the constructor.